# MySQL SELECT where if stores have X, show me everything that they have

Tags: mysql, sql, select

**I have a MYSQL table like this:**

```
STORES (SPID, StoreID, ProductID);
```

**And data like this:**

```
{ 1 | s1 | p2 }
{ 2 | s1 | p7 }
{ 3 | s1 | p8 }
{ 4 | s2 | p1 }
{ 5 | s2 | p3 }
{ 6 | s2 | p6 }
{ 7 | s2 | p9 }
{ 8 | s3 | p2 }
{ 9 | s3 | p5 }
```

**And I would like to:**
Use a MYSQL SELECT query to get results, where if a store has a certain product, then a list of all of the products at that store will be returned.
For example, if I were looking for "p2", then I would like to know that "s1" has "p2, p7, p8" and "s3" has "p2, p5".

Please let me know if you require any more information. I'm not sure what is required to solve this issue (Which is probably why I can't search and find the answer!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM STORES WHERE StoreID IN (SELECT StoreID FROM Stores WHERE ProductID='p2')
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to use a `WHERE IN` or `WHERE EXISTS` approach to select all rows from stores that are in the list of stores with the target product.

```
SELECT
    StoreID
    , ProductID
FROM
    Stores
WHERE
    StoreID IN 
        (SELECT
            StoreID
        FROM
            Stores
        WHERE
            ProductID IN ('p2')
                /*also, using IN here in the sub query will allow
                you to specify more than one product in the future*/
        )
```

Alternatively, you could join the table with itself:

```
SELECT
    S.StoreID
    , S.ProductID
FROM
    Stores S
    INNER JOIN Stores SProd
        ON S.StoreID = SProd.StoreID
WHERE
    SProd.ProductID IN ('p2')
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'll upvote it as soon as I get a bit higher reputation!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a self join. See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6507a/2/0) for testing.

```
select s1.storeid, s1.productid
from stores s1
join stores s2 on s2.storeid = s1.storeid
where s2.productid = 'p2'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the SQL Fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  st1.store_id, st1.product_id, st2.store_id, st2.product_id
from
  stores st1
join
  stores st2 on st2.store_id = st1.store_id
where
  st1.product_id='p2'
order by store_id, product_id
```